# How to refresh Font Awesome icon on Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, font-awesome

**Is there any way to change font awesome icon dynamically?** I want user to be able to select one of font awesome icons dynamically. It works only when you add class first time. The place where I try to do it is - `MatDialog`. There is form where user have to select icon, background color and category name. To select icon user should open another dialog.

[image]     [image]

I'm using `Angular 9.1.4` and `Font Awesome 5.13.0`.

---

That's what I tried:

### 1. Using ngClass

**category-dialog.component.html**

```html
<div [ngStyle]="selectedColor">
    <i [ngClass]="selectedIcon"></i>
</div>
```

**category-dialog.component.ts**

```js
openIconDialog(): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogIconSelectComponent, { width: '15rem' });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.selectedIcon = result;
  });
}
```

> **This works only first time. But when you try to change icon `selectedIcon` changes, but UI doesn't refresh element class.**

---

### 2. Using @ViewChild

```js
@ViewChild('iconElement') iconElement: ElementRef;

constructor(private dialog: MatDialog,
            private renderer: Renderer2) { }

openIconDialog(): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogIconSelectComponent, { width: '15rem' });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: string) => {
    this.iconElement.nativeElement.className = result;
  });
}
```

> **This also works only first time.**

---

### 3. Using @ViewChild and Renderer2

**category-dialog.component.html**

```html
<div #colorElement [ngStyle]="selectedColor">
    <i #iconElement></i>
</div>
```

**category-dialog.component.ts**

```js
@ViewChild('colorElement') parentElement: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('iconElement') childElement: ElementRef;

constructor(private dialog: MatDialog,
            private renderer: Renderer2) { }

openIconDialog(): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogIconSelectComponent, { width: '15rem' });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.replaceIcon(result);
  });
}

replaceIcon(iconClass: string): void {
  const i = this.renderer.createElement('i');
  this.renderer.setProperty(i, 'class', iconClass);
  this.renderer.removeChild(this.parentElement.nativeElement, this.childElement);
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.parentElement.nativeElement, i);
}
```

> **That doesn't work at all.**

---

Is there any way how to change font awesome dynamically?

Comment: can you setup a stackblitz with minimum functionality?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-style-attribute-of-an-element-dynamically-using-javascript/

Comment: @Frost Whats is similar between HTML element style and `<i>` (italic text) tag class (`fas fa-home`)?

Comment: @WahabShah I guess it's enough information here

Comment: @mplungjan You're totally wrong here, because as you see I tried common methods for angular, but that doesn't work for `<i>` or/and with `fa` classes

Comment: "Totally wrong", thanks for your assessment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Resolution

Wasted lot of my free time to investigate how to resolve this issue. Tried everything with `Renderer2` and all dirty Javascript methods. But one day I came up with idea to use `innerHtml`.

Rendering new string of inner HTML changes Font Awesome icons interactively.

#### category-dialog.component.html

```
<div [ngStyle]="selectedColor" [innerHtml]="selectedIconHtml"></div>
```

#### category-dialog.component.ts

```js
openIconDialog(): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogIconSelectComponent, { width: '15rem' });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: string) => {
    // EVERY TIME NEW ELEMENT WITH NEW FA CLASS
    this.selectedIconHtml = `<i class="${result}"></i>`;
  });
}
```

> This solution - on every icon selection's changing `<div>` element content (inner html).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue like this:

```
<div innerHTML="<i class='{{icon}}'></i>">
</div>
```

In this case, icon will be rerendered after value changes. `innerHTML` makes this happen easily. No need any code in TS file.